# Button positioning issue in Relative Layout

Tags: android, button

I got a problem in a project with the [following](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ypqv2) structure. On each emulator (also large screens) a button positioned within a simple relative layout using that code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/first_bg" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="202dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/m_button"
        android:text="@string/next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

appears fine. BUT testing the app on Galaxy Note has shown that the button just flies away to some crazy positions. I used an emulator with similar configuration and the button appeared properly. I have no idea where the problem could be..

Comment: I guess you arrange the button's place on the GUI editor of the adt-plugin and it gives you these margins. Instead try writing the GUI directly in the xml or use the GUI but watch if the editor add margins or not by itself.

Comment: I've tried both ways and also a Linear Layout with margins defined by hand.. but that goddamn button just doesn't want to stay at the proper place when launching the app on Galaxy Note o_0

Comment: Clean your project and uninstall it from the phone. Then try again sometimes xml resources are messed up. However, I guess there's something wrong with your xml. You can post a screenshot of how it should be and how it appears right now with the last xml you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a linearlayout instead?
With it you don't nedd to set the margin, just the position

Answer (score 0):

It's based on the density-independent pixels (dp units), it'll show up at different positions on different phones.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence